# How to post data from CKEditor to json server in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm trying to build a webpage to perform CRUD operations. How can I get data from Ckeditor and post in Json server in React?

> This is my code

> > Note: This Code is Working fine for normal input form but in the Ckeditor section it's not working

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useHistory, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from '../Header/Header';
import bgpic from './a215_1_cover_image.jpg';

import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

const AddPost = () => {
  let history = useHistory();
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    title: '',
    img: '',
    body: '',
  });

  const { title, img, body } = user;

  const onInputChange = (e) => {
    setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/post', user);
    history.push('/');
  };
return (
    <>
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='w-75 mx-auto shadow p-5'>
          <h2 className='text-center mb-4'>Your Blog</h2>

          <form onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}>
            <div className='form-group'>
              <input
                type='text'
                required
                className='form-control form-control-lg'
                placeholder='Title'
                name='title'
                value={title}
                onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
              />
            </div>

            <div className='form-group'>
              <CKEditor
                name='body'
                value={body}
                editor={ClassicEditor}
                onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}></CKEditor>
            </div>

          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default AddPost;
```

> Whenever I'm trying to write on text editor section, This is the error

[image]

Comment: CKEditor encapsulates the data in html tags. So, you need to filter them first.
```dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data }}```

Comment: Second,
```<div className='form-group'>
              <CKEditor
                name='body'
                value={body}
                editor={ClassicEditor}
                onChange={() => onInputChange()}></CKEditor>
            </div>```

Comment: ```await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/post', user)
    .then(() => history.push('/'))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))```

Comment: @ZahirMasoodi In my code where should i use ```dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data }}```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event and editor to get data (as shown below):

```js
<CKEditor editor={ClassicEditor} onChange={(event, editor) => setData(editor.getData())} />
```